# Get attribute of element in rendered UI with JavaScript in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to get or change a attribute of a Javascript element in Shiny. So in the example below, I would like to obtain the `iframe` width directly when it is rendered using Javascript. I know I can set the width of the `iframe`, but that is not the goal. I would like to be able to get other attributes than width as well, for example the `frameBorder` attribute of an `iframe`.

[Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) it says that "The last event to be fired for x is `shiny:value`", so I assumed binding to that would work:

```
library(shiny)

jsCode <- tags$head(tags$script(HTML( "
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(e){
  if (e.target.id === 'my_iframe')
    {
     alert('JS code is running now.');
     console.log(e);
     var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
     console.log(iframe.width);
    }
})")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  jsCode,
  uiOutput('my_iframe')
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$my_iframe <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src='http://www.example.com/', height=600)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, we can see that the `alert` already fires before the `iframe` is actually rendered(?) So my question; how can I obtain the width (or any other attribute, such as `frameborder`, see the image below) of the `iframe` with Javascript directly when it is rendered?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the event `DOMNodeInserted`. As soon as an `iframe` is added to the DOM, your code will be executed:

```
$('html').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function() {
  alert("Fire in the hole!");
  # Getting and setting CSS properties
  $(this).css('background');                  # get
  $(this).css('background-color', '#330000'); # set

  # Getting elements attributes
  $(this).attr('frameborder');      # get
  $(this).attr('frameborder', '0'); # set
});
```

Notice that the `frameborder` attribute is not actively set and therefore our `attr()` call returns `undefined`. You still see a `frameborder` though since it's default value is `1` (turned on).

Comment: Hi @Martin, thanks for the solution approach. However, I am still not sure how to get any property from the `iframe`, such as the `frameBorder`. I might not have specified this clearly enough in my question, sorry for that.

Comment: You mean the CSS properties? Just check `css()` in the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: e.g. `$(this).css('border');` ?

Comment: Or the `iframe`s `frameborder` attribute by `$(this).attr('frameborder');`

Comment: I indeed do not mean the CSS property, but the iframe attribute. I did not realize they were called attributes... `$(this).attr('frameborder');` returns 'undefined' for me though? That is also the case for any other attributes I try to obtain.

Comment: Sure, if you go to the browser an inspect the iframe, you wont find any other attribute besides `href`. They are not set. therefore `undefined`.

Comment: So after adding a frameborder to the iframe `tags$iframe(src='http://www.example.com/', height=600, frameborder="1")` you will get the expected output.

Comment: Awesome! I saw `frameborder=""`, so I assumed ' "" ' was what I was supposed to obtain. This seems to work :) Thanks for the help.